# Order processing waitlist participants

Tags: waitlist

I'm experiencing that the persons on the waitlist gets offered a place in the wrong order. What I see is that the last person to register gets offered first. Which is of course backwards how I want it ;-)

Is this configurable so I have missed to set it correctly? Or is this something about date comparisons? (I'm running a Swedish site). Or some other bug?

Comment: Is there someone who can confirm what I'm seeing? Or find that it works the way it should, first on the queue gets offered a seat first?